# Where to set the ModelMetadataprovider with DI when using MVC Turbine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, metadata, turbine

To use your own ModelMetadataProvider you normally set it in the global.asax.

I'm using MVC Turbine and I need to inject a dependency into my ModelMetadataProvider as well.

Something like this:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyModelMetadataProvider(ISomeDependency);
```

How is this best accomplished with MVC Turbine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to put these pieces is to override the Startup method within your web application (the type that inherits from TurbineApplication).  We're currently working on making these MVC2 features easier in v2.2 by introducing a ModelMetadataBlade that will do all the wiring up for you to the ModelMetadataProvider.Current property.

So all you'll have to do is register MyModelMetadataProvider with the container like so

```
container.Register<ModelMetadataProvider, MyModelMetadataProvider>()
```

then MVC Turbine will do the rest for you. To get an idea of what I'm talking about, checkout the way [we're wiring up ModelValidatorProviders](http://github.com/jglozano/mvcturbine/blob/master/src/Blades/MVC2/MvcTurbine.Mvc2/ModelValidatorBlade.cs). The ModelValidatorBlade asks the ServiceLocator for all the registered ModelValidatorProvider and wires them up with the runtime.

If you have any feedback or ideas, could you post them to the [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mvcturbine)? Trying to keep these things organized :)

Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I now get an exteption in my view when call Html.EditorForModel(). "An instance of ModelMetadataProvider was found in the resolver as well as a custom registered provider in ModelMetadataProviders.Current. Please set only one or the other." I am not setting ModelMetadataProviders.Current anywhere...